# Trait instance as template parameter for different trait

Tags: c++, templates, traits

I am creating a trait with a template, which has as template parameter a trait instance. The code is more complicated, but for this question I keep the code simple. The code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>


template<int i>
struct A
{
    static const int value = i;
};


template<typename a>
struct B
{
    static const int value = a::value;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::cout << A<3>::value << std::endl; // 3
  std::cout << B< A<3> >::value << std::endl; // 3
  return 0;
}
```

This works, but now I want to change `typename` to something like `A<int i>` to make sure `B` can only be called when you pass an instance of `A<int i>` as template parameter.
If I do this I get the following error:

> test.cpp:11:17: error: template argument 1 is invalid
>   template<\A<\int i> a>
>                  ^
>   test.cpp:14:30: error: 'a' has not been declared
>      static const int value = a::value;
>                               ^

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I do this?

Using specialization

```
template <typename>
struct B;

template <int I>
struct B<A<I>>
 { static const int value = A<I>::value; }; // or also value = I;
```